# Chrome Responsive Emulator - How to default zoom to 100%

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools, emulation

One of the most annoying things I encounter on a daily basis is constantly having to reset the zoom of the chrome device emulator.

For whatever reason, each time I change the device selection, the zoom changes from 100% to the "Fit to Window" size, which is always less than 100% and renders the page and text so tiny its unusable.

I've seen the "Edit" menu under the device listing, and this is where I would expect to find the setting to always default the zoom to 100%, however, I'm not seeing it there. What am I missing?

Comment: good question. Exactly what i am searching for

Comment: I would like to know an answer to this as well ) so far it doesn't seem to be possible (in latest Chrome version at least).

Comment: Pretty late to ask something on this thread, but is the real text size on physical devices close to their size when displaying in 100% zoom in chrome? Or they're smaller in real scale? I mean, there must be a reason that the inspect tool auto-adjusts zoom value.

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem for a while. Go to the right top menu as you see in the picture. Click on "Reset to defaults". It worked for me.

[image: chrome developer tools]

Comment: Please use "Add Image" button in the answer editor to insert images so that they would actually show in the post.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! This saves me a lot of hair from being teared out.

Comment: Worked for me on a Mac when nothing else did, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In the same menu where you are resetting the zoom percentage (the "Edit" menu you mentioned), you will see an option called "Auto-adjust zoom". Uncheck that option and set your zoom to 100%. [image]

Comment: The "Reset to Defaults" solution did not work for me but this one did!

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Despite older solutions, I found that the **device ratio** is the main problem in recreating a device viewport. The dev tools `pixel device ratio` input doesn't seme to work as expected. For me, the only reliable method is to use **viewport size** instead of resolution with **pixel ratio blank**. The added benefit is testing when users have a bookmarks bar open in Chrome or side pane open in Safari.

**Caveat**: "Auto-Adjust Zoom" and "Fit to Window" won't work with these methods... if you have a large screen and are working on a small UI use the preset zoom levels 100%, 125%, etc.

**The Manual Method**

Here's a walkthrough I use with a macbook pro as an example (screen res 2880x1800 pixel-ratio 2).

1. Get a screenshot from the user with your website open on their device (**make sure page zoom is reset**, e.g. cmd+0 or ctrl+0)
2. Open the screenshot, measure the pixels of the webpage only. My example user had the bookmarks bar open, and I measured the viewport as **2880 by 1514**.
3. Divide the above by the device ratio to get the viewport. Macbook Pro is 2.

   - `2880/2` = `1440`
   - `1514/2` = `757`
4. Compensate for the bookmarks bar height, add `23` pixels to the height.

   - `757` + `23` = `780`
5. Create a custom responsive profile (width first):

   - Width: `1440`
   - Height: `780`
   - Device pixel ratio: ____ (leave blank)

Now selecting that profile will default to 100% and is an exact match to the user.

**The Programmatic Method** (collecting user viewports)

In supporting more devices, this is a reoccurring problem for me. I ended up automating viewport measurement by adding the JS below to measure the viewport, and it gets sent back and stored in a db with the user's session.

```js
const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);
const vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0);

console.log(`ViewPortWidth=${vw}`); // 1440 
console.log(`ViewPortHeight=${vh}`); // 780

// Example of how to collect analytics on user viewports
const user = Users.getActiveUser(); // pretend fn call
user.addCurrentViewPort(vw, vh);
user.persist();
```

Later on, query the db and see what viewports your users use... add new responsive test profiles.