# Stop Chrome from auto-adjusting my zoom or width in Developer Tools - Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, google-chrome-devtools

As many of you are probably aware, Chrome has an annoying "feature" where it auto adjusts the zoom so the content "fits to window" when you have the Chrome Dev Tools open and the Device Toolbar enabled.

If you change the zoom back to 100% then it changes the width to something that will fit, so you literally can't change either as it forces one of the other back to a setting so it will fit in the window.

Now, I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45695394/472501), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45530211/472501), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495698/472501) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52304425/472501), none of which work.

I have also recently reinstalled Windows 7 and it still works the same as it did before the reinstall.

I'm running on Windows 7 if that matters.

Is there any other settings that this could probably be to stop it from doing this!?

Comment: When I turn off "Auto-adjust zoom", Chrome crops the page if it is too large for the viewport at that zoom level. You say it doesn't work — what happens instead?

Comment: @JoshLee From what I can tell, absolutely nothing happens, having it checked or not checked it seems to act _exactly_ the same.

Comment: @Brett Just so there's no misinterpretation - Is this what you're trying to achieve ? https://i.imgur.com/AXWvavJ.png

Comment: @hmedia1 No, no - this is when I have the toggle device toolbar open.

Comment: Pretty late to ask something on this thread, but is the real text size on physical devices close to their size when displaying in 100% zoom in chrome? Or they're smaller in real scale? I mean, there must be a reason that the inspect tool auto-adjusts zoom value. –